# Stop Highcharts Networkgraph from redrawing the markers when hovering

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm working on a network graph and somebody helped get me to the point where I can hide/show nodes when clicking on them. However, there seems to be default behaviour which redraws the nodes when you move the mouse at all.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLbkpsag/. You'll see that clicking a node hides its children, however if you mouse the mouse after clicking then the node reappears.

I added in

```js
addClass('hide-tree-element')
```

which has helped on the dataLabel, but the marker or "graphic" redraws every time.

It seems that there is default behaviour to "dim other series" when hovering https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9899. Which I thought might be affecting it. I've tried disabling that but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the inactive state redraws each point on `mouseOut` event.

To change this default behavior you can simply wrap `Highcharts.Series.prototype.onMouseOut` method and remove the piece of code responsible for removing inactive state functionality (added here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/f86f50f80160f078bd185e8e5db1251f317f9fff#diff-12c0e234e06f670ee77d64cce2a9205dL768):

```
// Reset all inactive states
chart.series.forEach(function (series) {
   series.setState('', true);
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zrL8w067/

Comment: Thanks so much! That is really helpful.

Comment: Hi @wojciech - I wondered if you could help me. I'm struggling to be able to get a node's "grandchildren" to hide/show when clicked. Any ideas? I was trying to "trigger" a click on `link.id` but it's not working. So when David Harrison is clicked I'd want the address and Alan Ball to hide too. Happy to ask this as a separate question if needed. Thanks very much.

Comment: You can achieve it going further in links reference chain. Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xsLnmd0u/

Comment: Hi @Wojciech, thanks very much for that. Seems I can now go up the chain and hide them so that's great. One issue I'm seeing, which is related to the original question. It seems that the "click" event also redraws the nodes. So if you click one it hides the child no problem, but then clicking on a different node will show just the marker of the originally hidden node. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a default networkgraph behavior. To change it you have to overwrite the `render` method and after points are re-rendered hide them again. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4tgb9jcx/1/