# Collapsible node in highchart network graph in Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I am also working on this feature like onclick node would be collapsible in network graph but I am stuck into error. Error is

> Property 'linksHidden' does not exist on type 'Point'.ts(2339)

I am using highchart in angular application. I am using @Wojciech Chmiel code snippet. which is mentioned in screenshot.

**Linked Answer:** [Showing/Hiding child nodes and links in Highcharts Networkgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135011/showing-hiding-child-nodes-and-links-in-highcharts-networkgraph/61233117#61233117)

[image: Error code screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10077925/wojciech-chmiel, please help me :(

Comment: Could you reproduce your current attempt with the sample data on some online editor which I could work on? You can use this template: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-5l2wm

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I am done with sample data on your given online editor.
I want the feature into this is, when I click on relation node so its child node collapse and on another click child nodes expand
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-74fcr?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for the demo. It seems that it works fine, I haven't seen any errors. Could you explain where the issue is?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Thanks you so much for your time and yes this is also surprise for me there is no error but one thing I notice in my code is version of highchart, at my side the versions are as follows
** "highcharts": "^8.0.4" ** and **  "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0" **
but in sample code the library versions are as follows
 ** "highcharts": "7.0.0" ** and **  "highcharts-angular": "2.3.1" **

I think that's why error at my side.

In one thing I need your  help which is, when initially chart load so the child nodes of relations are closed. How this can be achieved?

Comment: I upgraded the version to the current one and still, there is no error. Back to your question - you can hide the child nodes using the `chart.events.load` callback on the initial load. Here is a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-gdxcn

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, I don't know why I am still getting an error in code as shown in screenshot, I am adding package.json file with the name 'mypackage.json' , kindly review this file I think there is version problem with my code and another thing is that I need to hide both nodes and edges but currently only edges hide

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-74fcr?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

"mypackage.json" file is here

Comment: hm, it seems that the problem which you are struggling to is related to TypeScript, but I am not sure why it exists in your local project but doesn't in the demo. Try to set the `points.linkHidden` as any or defined it before the chart will be initialized.  Back to your second part of the question - you can use the `hide` feature to hide `fromNode` or `linkTo` graphic - but I am not sure which ones do you want to hide.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, I have recreated a problem which is not work as expected.
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-gdxcn?file=/src/app/app.component.ts.

I need this type of functionality as work in this link
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xsLnmd0u/

Comment: I think that the previous solution had some mistakes. What can you say about this one? Please test it and confirm is that what you need to implement: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9mv0ny3j/